# insert query in C# with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my insert query, I don't know the mistake.

```
string strcon = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=userinformation; Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(strcon);
mycon.Open();

string strquery = "insert into userdetails(firstname,lastname,gender,)VALUES('" + firstname + "','" + lastname + "','" + gender + "')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, mycon);
mycon.Close();
MessageBox.Show("the value has been inserted");
```

Comment: remove comma after gender column then try to insert and put Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: yeah i found it friend...now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually executing the command.  Directly before the call to `mycon.Close()`, call the command by using:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Correct SQLCommand is not an auto execute, read the basic functioning, any sample will show the working of SqlCommand